# How to print a LinkButton to page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, linkbutton

Say I have a dynamically generated LinkButton in my ascx.cs code-behind. How could I go about "printing" this control to my page? Obviously I can't do something like just print the Text property as I need the button to retain its hyperlink. I'm guessing I want to use the WebControl.Render method, but I'm not familiar with it at all and haven't been able to find a good example of its use.

Comment: My answer shows you, how you can achieve what you want to do with your initial idea of the RenderControl method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/3/asp.net/create-a-control-in-the-codebehind-and-retrieve-its-rendered-output should explain the basics of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a label at the right location in the page: `<asp:Label id="myLinkButtonPlace" runat="server"></asp:Label>`, and in code, you could add the linkbutton to the controlcollection of the label: `this.myLinkButtonPlace.Controls.Add(aLinkButton);`

Comment: I can't access myLinkButtonPlace from the code. When I try to do myLinkButtonPlace.Controls.Add(button) it doesn't recognize myLinkButtonPlace.

Comment: Not even if you try to build it? Sometimes the VS develope time compiler runs a little behind on the markup of asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @Joachim VR, there are many other asp.net controls with which you can add a dynamically created control to.

```
<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" />
<asp:PlaceHolder id="Placeholder1" runat="server" />
<asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" />
```

The above would render HTML different.
So the Label would render as a `<span id="Label1"><a></a></span>`
Panel as <`div id="Placeholder1"><a></a></div>`
The Placeholder would simply render as the `<a></a>`